# ASP.NET basic site structure for navigation

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, navigation

I have now browsed many forums for answer to a quite basic question, but to my surprise I can't find a good example of a very basic design that most sites uses. I am not new to programming but it was a while ago I worked more substantial with it and I am totally new to ASP.NET. I am currently working with VS2010 and building an ASP.NET MVC 3 site from scratch. The site is AJAX enabled and I am currently using both an According control for left pane navigation and a TabContainer for top tab navigation.

Everything so far is included in one master page, and the basic problem is that when selecting navigation links in the left/top menus, the entire page reloads and destroys states for the navigational menus. Also, there is totally unnecessary flickering and I see no reason for reloading the entire page, I only want to change contents of the "main area" without touching the navigation menus.

The site structure is currently built up with `<DIV>` elements which makes the design quite straight forward and a structure of CSS files provides great flexbility and control. From recommendations I would like to do whatever I can to avoid obsolete solutions such as IFrames. I want to make a foundation for how this can be done in a modern and flexible way, with as few compromises as possible. It is important since the system I have started might be worked on by an entire team after having passed a number of decision forums.

I have as I as said browsed quite extensively for solutions, and found many explanations on the concept of master pages that gives me input to what my problems seems to be: my navigation menus are bound to a master page, a master page is really only a "user control" that connects tightly to the content pages and these merged pages reload when I select a navigation link. And that is not supposed to happen, it is not acceptable.

I have also tried to wrap the loading of the navigational panels in "!IsPostBack" conditions, but I've come to the conclusion that the problem is not PostBack:s, the problem is that a click on a link/treelink/accordion pane in the left menu really requests a totally new page and so everything reloads and the former state is lost. Of course I could write code to store states and provide the "new page" with the last states, this would be a solution if nothing else is possible; but I really don't want to reload the entire page; I only want to reload the "main area" to decrease bandwidth need and also avoid flickering.

So I have searched for ways of only update the "main content contentplaceholder" and I see many questions on this subject but very few good answers, and especially not when I want to change the entire aspx page in the main area, not just update a number of controls (or dynamically create new ones/delete old ones etc). The reason for the urge to change the entire aspx page is that different pages will provide different functionality and it is not enough by simply manipulating some controls, but the main area should be loaded with another aspx page - from a development organisation perspective it is also good since different developers can then work on different areas of functionality in the full blown application.

I am willing to abandon the entire master page strategy, or used nested master pages, or wrap master pages in non-master pages, or use updatepanels, or use cross page postings or whatever. But I find no example of something that actually works that I can use as a start.

And, since this is basically at this point only client side updates, I can't really understand why this should become such a tricky thing to straigthen out.

So, very simply put my question is this: what would you consider to be the basic strategy for designing a site where I have navigational menus (top and left) that can load new aspx pages into a certain area (main area) and ONLY update this area and NOT the entire site.

If you can provide me with some description of this and of course preferably some demo site where only a portion of a site is updated with a new page but not the full page - it is as simple as that! - when this would be extremely welcome. Spent three days now browsing for a good recommedation and I just get more and more confused... :-(

Would be very grateful for directions.

/DT

Comment: I see that there is a lost part in the first sentence of the third text block: the sentence should say "The site structure is currently built up with '<DIV>' elements which makes..."

Comment: Uhm, is there a short version? -_-

Comment: Yes I just sent out the quintessence in a separate thread, repeated here: "I want to design a very standard site where the user gets the opportunity to navigate to different aspx pages with the aid of navigation menus (left, top). I do not want the entire page to be reloaded when changing the content page for three reasons: state handling, flickering and bandwidth conservation. I just want to load a new aspx page into a "main content area" with the rest of the site untouched. What is the best way to achieve this?"

Comment: It sounds like you are using Webforms and not MVC3 is that correct? Also, what version of .net are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is right that this test site is built as a webforms site. It should be MVC3. But I gather that this question is fairly general to both but I might be severely mistaken, again I am a newbie to ASP.NET. The .NET version should be 4.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a master page layout. Have a `ContentPlaceHolder` for the navigation (as many as you need) and another for the main content. You can then use something like `JQuery.ajax()` or ASP.NETs built in `UpdatePanel` to load content into the main ContentPlaceHolder when required.

With regards to the content itself I would use UserControls (.ascx files). You can pass a command to your default page to tell it which Control to load and then just load it.

I would personally use ASP.NETs UpdatePanel as you can force it to load new content using `UpdatePanel.Update();`.

One thing to note though is if this is for an actual website that requires search engine optimisation it may be difficult to do because the Url won't be changing so SEO will suffer.

It's a broad example but HTH.

Edit:

I would do 2 things:

1. Add a `PlaceHolder` to default.aspx (within an `UpdatePanel`) and expose it in the code behind as a public var so it can be access externally.
2. Expose the `UpdatePanel` so it can be accessed externally;

So on default you would have something like:

```
<asp:Content id="Content1" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="cphContent">
    <asp:UpdatePanel id="updMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder id="phMain" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

On Navigation Control do this for all the navigation links (changing the OnClick to suit the control to be loaded - this could be done in a repeater and dynamically):

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lbItem" runat="server" onClick="LoadControl1" />
```

Then in the codebehind (of the navigation) you could have:

```
protected void LoadControl1(object sender, EventArgs)
{
    MyControl Con = (MyControl)LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx");
    ((Default)Page).phMain.Controls.Add(Con);
    ((Default)Page).updMain.Update();
}
```

Note, you could achieve the same thing without the complexity of Master Pages but I prefer them. If you wanted to do it without a master page then you just have `PlaceHolders` on default and do the same thing.

**Edit 2:**

You could also do this using JQuery() by loading content into a div. Have your page setup (MasterPage or Normal page structure). Then have your navigation links like so:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page1.aspx" class="ajax_link">Link 1</a>
```

Then have some Javascript (using JQuery):

```
$(function(){
    $("a.ajax_link").click(function(e){
        ajaxLink(this, e);
    });
});

function ajaxLink(item, e) {
    var container = $("#ajax_container_wrapper");
    var link;

    if (e != null) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    link = $(item).attr("href") + " #ajax_container_wrapper"; //Omit the  + " #ajax_container_wrapper"; if you want to drag all the content in.
    container.load(link);
}
```

And have:

```
<div id="ajax_container_wrapper"></div>
```

Where you want the new pages to appear.

This will basically load a new page specified in each of the links into the div.

Comment: Thanks. But how to use an updatepanel for this? I have tried with no success, and when reading pages like these http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2007/01/04/ajax-updatepanels-and-contentplaceholders.aspx I get the feeling that it might not even be possible?

Comment: Sorry if I am really stupid now, but here you add a control..? I want to load an aspx page...

Comment: Why does it have to be a Page? You don't want a page refresh so it would make sense to me to just load a control into the Page you have (Default).

Comment: OK, I start to see that this is a big point of confusion and I am baffled about this. But I really want to switch from one aspx page to another. Is this possible?

Comment: OK great my next attempt will be this latest stuff - I will try it next week. I also made a brief attempt with the other solution but with no success so far.It might be me not trying hard enough. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: The second one is a lot easier to implement so you should be able to get it working with relative ease. Don't forget to mark as the answer if it works out for you ;)

Comment: Added an answer, now when I look at it I see it is above your answer for some reason. It should be here anyway...

Comment: You shouldn't of added that as an answer as it doesn't solve the problem. If you have questions about my answer you need to ask them here.

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand the forum functionality...is it so that you can't see my answer (there or some tiny code excerpts in it)? My main question to your solution are
1) that I can't get the JavaScript function to be called so the full page reloads
2) when it works; how can I execute the page change (still only in main content area) from code behind? (C#)

Comment: 1) If you are using the JS I posted, it won't reload the whole page. Check to make sure no errors are happening in the in the console. 2) You can't do this from the code behind. You need to go with my original suggestion if you want to do that.

Comment: 1) I have entered the JavaScript on the Master page, and I have used the anchor lines you provided, with class="ajax_link" but the JavaScript is not called 2) Are you saying it is impossible to change an aspx page to another from code behind?? Your original suggestion does not change aspx pages, which was my original question.

Comment: OK, I have seen some threads on this subject: how to update only the content part of a page based on the master page concept, without reloading menus, status bars and similar. No thread found so far resulting in a working solution. This one was close, at least it is stated that it actually "should be possible" which seemed promising but unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how the jQuery code should be used and obviously on one else either, so here we have another thread resulting in the "no solution" state. Now let's try the "cross page posting" strategy.

Comment: OK it did not work out either. Neither did Iframes since I found no way of doing "cross-frame-updates" of individual controls such as e. g. Labels. Giving up. Going for the unaccepatably stupid "save states - reload the entire page - restore states"-strategy. ASP.NET really sucks.

Comment: No offence but this isn't a restriction in ASP.NET, you must be implementing it incorrectly. My example with UpdatePanels WILL work, I know this as I did it last month.

Comment: I thought you said that it is impossible to change aspx-pages in a part of a site via code behind...which is of course a very fundamental requirement. At least "of course" for me.

Comment: No, you can change pages from the code behind but you have to use UpdatePanels, not JQuery. My advised method is to use controls though as they can be placed into PlaceHolders which makes the whole thing very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps a step taken - your code works in the sense that it changes pages. But as far as I can tell, the entire page is still reloaded and not only the main content area which is what I struggle to do.

What I did was that I placed the javascript code - unaltered- you provided in the master page.

**Edit** Just realized that the java functions seem not to be called. So the anchors provide "standard" functionality, which might be a clue :-) How can I make the javascript to be called (as stated below also from code behind)? I leave the rest of this answer as is just to check for additional errors. **/Edit**

Then I placed two anchors on the bottom of the left nav menu (still in the master page)

```
<div id="navcol">

    <%-- other left menu stuff --%>

    <a href="../ContentPages/FutureStartPage.aspx" class="ajax_link">Link 1</a>
    <a href="../ContentPages/BusCoachStartPage.aspx" class="ajax_link">Link 2</a>

</div>
```

I placed the target div in the main content section, also in the master page. I also tested to have the div id="ajax_container_wrapper" inside the contentplace holder and the contentplaceholder inside div id="ajax_container_wrapper" the unfortunately I saw no difference in behaviour.

```
<div id="contentcol" runat="server">
    <div id="mpcpholder">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderMainArea" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div id="ajax_container_wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

I also tried to omit the ContentPlaceHolder but this seem not to be allowed; it gave a parser error.

So probably I done something wrong, but it is crystal clear that the full page is reloading including the top and left menus.

Also; if I get it to work with ONLY reloading the main content area; I need to do this both from e. g. treeview link and even more important from code behind. I would appreciate some advice on how to that as well.

Thanks
/DT